# What is the font used in these images?

Tags: font-identification

What is the font used by in these images below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Arkadiusz, we have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [Cormac](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typedepot/cormac/) in light or book weight, it's pretty expensive.

But maybe you can get by with [Noto Sans](https://www.fontzillion.com/fonts/google/noto-sans?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=matcherator_link&utm_campaign=notosans) or perhaps [FranKlein](https://www.fontzillion.com/fonts/manfred-klein/franklein?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=matcherator_link&utm_campaign=franklein) which are free.

Comment: Thanks @mayersdesign! I wanted to use Source Sans Pro but Noto Sans is more similar to Cormac.

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help :)